# How and why does an electron add up (enters) in the valance shell of an atom?

Tags: atomic-physics, physical-chemistry, binding-energy

How does an electron add up (enters) in the valance shell of an atom? Why is energy released when an electron adds up in the valance shell of an isolated atom.

Comment: Want read this answer https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/553010/does-a-9-192-631-770-hz-hyperfine-transition-create-9-192-631-770-photons-per-se/553394#553394 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Energy isn't always released when an electron is added to an atom. It depends on the kind of atom you are adding the electron to.

Energy is released if the electronegative atom attains a more stable state by accepting the electron (by say attaining a octet configuration in the valence shell). Stable states have less energy when compared to other states and this difference in energy is released when an atom accepts an electron.

On the other hand, it actually requires energy to add an electron to an electropositive atom which has an extra shell of electrons which makes it unstable. To add another electron we would have to overcome the repulsions due the already present electrons and hence energy would have to be supplied rather than it being released.
If by how an electron entere you mean that how does an atom gain or lose electrons,its to complete its octet configuration.For example when Mg reacts with o2 As O has 2 less electrons to reach its octet whilst Mg has 2 extra electrons.Mg gives its electrons to O for both of them to complete their octet.This is known as an Ionic bond.Hope it helps

Comment: Does this depend on closeness of electron from atom?

Comment: I don't understand what are you saying?

Comment: If an electron is close to the valance shell of an atom only then an electron can enter valance shell? Or it can also enter if it is far?

Comment: There is a force known as electrostatic force,which depends on the charges,the electrons will enter depending on the distance as the proton in the nucleus would attract ot whilst the other electrons would repel it.The electrostatic force is proportional to 1/r^2 where R is the distance.So it will definitely depend from where its coming.